# DbTableGateway is not writing my session information to database table

Tags: zend-framework2, php, zend-session

I'm trying to use DbTableGateway to store my session information in a MySQL database--but my "sessions" table is remaining empty.  It never contains any rows.  Here's my code (more or less copy/pasted from [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.session.save-handler.html)):

```
$dbAdapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'database' => 'db-name',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password!'
));
$tableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('session', $dbAdapter);
$saveHandler = new \Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTableGateway($tableGateway, new \Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTableGatewayOptions());
$manager = new \Zend\Session\SessionManager();
$manager->setSaveHandler($saveHandler);

$someContainer = new Container('SomeSessionNamespace');
$someContainer->aBitOfData = 'tasty morsel of data';
```

And here's a video demonstration of me using this code:
http://screencast.com/t/UDDUs6OZOib

As you can see in the video, session information is preserved between requests, but it's not being stored in the database.

I added breakpoints to every function in `Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTableGateway`, and the only one that's getting hit is in __constructor.  So the constructor is getting called, but apparently it never gets used for anything else.

What am I missing?

I'm using Zend Framework 2.2.2 on PHP 5.3.

-Josh

Answer (score 1):

I found some modules to do that if you need to implement this quickly

1. https://github.com/Nitecon/DBSessionStorage
2. https://github.com/gabriel403/G403SessionDb

To use your current code, please check:

- options of ** DbTableGatewayOptions** (id, data, lifetime, etc..)

  ```
  $options = new \Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTableGatewayOptions();
  $options->setDataColumn('data');
  $options->setIdColumn('id');
  $options->setLifetimeColumn('lifetime');
  $options->setNameColumn('name');
  $options->setModifiedColumn('modified');
  ```
- the start of you SessionManager **$manager->start();**

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions, and I may got that route, but I would really like to understand why `Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTableGateway` is not working as I have it configured.

Comment: I tried adding `$manager->start()`.  No change.  Then I tried `$manager->start(true)`.  Still no change.  And I am not passing any options to DbTableGatewayOptions.  I'm doing the same as shown in the ZF documentation, linked to in my question.  But maybe the documentation is incomplete.  How am I supposed to setup the DbTableGatewayOptions object?

Comment: No change, still nothing showing in my session database.  :-(

Answer (score 1):

Check in application.config.php and make sure the Application module is at the top level

Also make sure that in 
`'vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php'` and 
`'vendor/composer/autoload_static.php'`
zend and zendxml library path added or not

eg : `'Zend' => array(vendorDir . '/ZF2/library'),
    'ZendXml' => array(vendorDir . '/ZF2/library')`